# Printing number of files in bash shell

Tags: bash

So I'm really new to bash, and was working on counting number of files in a certain directory which I figured out how to,

```
ls $1 | wc -l
```

But then, I want shell to print out " files" behind the number of files like this

```
3 files
```

I tried

```
ls $1 | wc -l
echo " files
```

But the output to this is

```
3
files
```

What would i have to do if i want them in a single line?

Comment: See [How can I get a count of files in a directory using the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1125/264812) for an explanation of why `ls ... | wc -l` doesn't work in general, and how to count files in a directory reliably.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies two serious problems with `ls $1 | wc -l`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

> echo $(ls $1 | wc -l) files

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with `printf` like

```
printf '%s files' "$(ls "$1" | wc -l)"
```

but that will have (rare) issues if there are filenames with newlines in it (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  A more reliable way to get the count is to use `file` like

```
printf '%s files' "$(find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -printf . | wc -c)"
```

which will have `find` print a "." for every file in the current directory, then we count those since the special characters in the filenames won't be present any more.  Though as written that `find` will also count "hidden" files, which the `ls` wouldn't do.  You can eliminate those like so if you want:

```
printf '%s files' "$(find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -not name '.*' -printf . | wc -c)"
```